# Simplest way of outputting a single XML tag into HTML tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a simple way to format that single `heading` and turn those heading tags into h3 tags in XSLT?

```
<webpage>
  <heading>Header</heading>
  <p> paragraph <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> more paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
  </ul> 
  <p>more paragraph<a href="http://www.potato.com">potato.com</a></p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <heading>heading</heading>
  <p> here comes a list:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>

</webpage>
```

The goal is to turn it into this

```
  <h3>Header</h3>
  <p> paragraph <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> more paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
  </ul> 
  <p>more paragraph<a href="http://www.potato.com">potato.com</a></p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <h3>heading</h3>
  <p> here comes a list:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
  <p>more paragraph</p>
```

This seems like it should work, but it does not:

```
  <xsl:variable name="webpage" select="document('webpage.xml')/webpage">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/webpage/heading">
      <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </h3>
    </xsl:template>    
  </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: See the edit. It seems that I've only iterated through the same thing multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="webpage" select="document('webpage.xml')/webpage"/>

    <!-- No input document - so we set the initial template to start when we call the transform --> 
    <xsl:template name="start">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$webpage/@*|$webpage/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This template is the identity transform and will copy everything from the input to the output unless there a template that is a better match -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This template overrides the identity transform and changes the heading to an h3 -->
    <xsl:template match="/webpage/heading">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="."/></h3>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the supplied input xml produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><webpage>
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p> paragraph <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> more paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
        <li>item6</li>
    </ul> 
    <p>more paragraph<a href="http://www.potato.com">potato.com</a></p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <h3>heading</h3>
    <p> here comes a list:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>
    <p>more paragraph</p>

</webpage>
```

Comment: I changed the template to be driven from document('webpage.xml') rather than an input document

Comment: Note that the output document is not valid xml as there is no root <webpage> element any more. Are you sure that this is what you need?

Comment: Yes. I have it all wrapped up in <html> tags. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, this still does not seem to transform it into <h3> for some reason... I copied and pasted the exact code. Are you sure about this?

Comment: I ran the code and cut and pasted my output. To be double sure, I changed the start template as follows '<xsl:template name="start">
        foo
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$webpage/@*|$webpage/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>' and checked that foo turned up

Comment: iggy2012 - how are you running it? There's nothing wrong with the code, so there must be something wrong with the way you're running it. Though I'm not sure the complication with the start template is there - it seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: Sorry about that Kevan. I was implementing this line with other code. It seemed that importing it from via the document() method was messing up the method. Thanks any way for everything.